# XPath 2.0: Retrieving nodes by attribute where value is case Insensitive

Tags: xpath, xml-namespaces, xpath-2.0

I am new to using XPath and I am trying to retrieve a node via its attribute but the problem is that the attribute is case insensitive meaning I won't exactly know how the string is cased in the document.

So for example:

Given the document:

```
<Document xmlns:my="http://www.MyDomain.com/MySchemaInstance">
  <Machines>
    <Machine FQDN="machine1.mydomain.com">
      <...>
    </Machine>
    <Machine FQDN="Machine2.MyDomain.Com">
      <...>
    </Machine>
  </Machines>
</Document>
```

If I want to retrieve the machine1 I would use the XPath:

```
//my:Machines/my:Machine/*[@FQDN='machine1.mydomain.com']
```

But a similar XPath to get machine2 would fail becuase the case does not match:

```
//my:Machines/my:Machine/*[@FQDN='machine2.mydomain.com']  //Fails
```

---

I have seen various posts mention using something like (I am not sure how to apply Namespaces to this):

```
translate(@FQDN, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```

But even if I got it to work it would be really cumbersome considering the number of times I would be using it.

---

Finally I have read that XPath 2.0 supports matches() and lower-case() but being new to XPath I don't understand how to apply them:

For example if I try the following I get an "Invalid Qualified name":
    //my:Machines/my:Machine/*[matches(@FQDN, '(?i)machine1.mydomain.com')]
    //my:Machines/my:Machine/*[lower-case(@FQDN, 'machine1.mydomain.com')]

---

Can someone provide a sample XPath that includes handling of Namespaces that would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your example XML and XPath statements don't match.

- The sample XML elements are not bound to a namespace. The "my" namespace-prefix is declared, but not used for those elements, so they are in the "no namespace".
- Your sample XPath is using predicate filters on the children of `Machine` rather than on the `Machine` element that has the `@FQDN`.

**You could use either of these methods to look for the value case-insensitive:**

- [`matches()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_matches.html) function, with a flag for case-insensitive matching:

  ```
  //Machines/Machine[matches(@FQDN,'machine2.mydomain.com','i')]
  ```
- [`upper-case()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_upper-case.html) function to evaluate the upper-case strings:

  ```
  //Machines/Machine[upper-case(@FQDN)=upper-case('machine2.mydomain.com')]
  ```
- [`lower-case()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_lower-case.html) function to evaluate the lower-case strings:

  ```
  //Machines/Machine[lower-case(@FQDN)=lower-case('machine2.mydomain.com')]
  ```

> Can someone provide a sample XPath that includes handling of
>   Namespaces that would work?

Not sure what you meant by the handling of namespaces, but if you wanted to match on those elements regardless of their namespace then you can use the wildcard operator for the namespace:

```
//*:Machines/*:Machine[matches(@FQDN,'machine2.mydomain.com','i')]
```